# socket.io endpoints, what/where are they coming from?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

In my very simple nodejs server application. I serve up socket.io (v2.2.0) with no express or http. Here is my code.

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', (client) => { 
    client.emit("welcome", "hello user");
 });
io.listen(3000);
```

(Through googling) I've found I can in my web browser, I can navigate to both
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/ and
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
Where are these 'endpoints' defined from? My code doesn't say anything about those 'endpoints', but yet they exist. Are these leftovers from past versions?

When I go to  http://localhost:3000/socket.io/ I get a 400 bad request with a JSON return message of

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

and when I go to http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js I get this

```
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],e):"object"==typeof exports?exports.io=e():t.io=e()}(this,function(){return function(t){function e(n){if(r[n])return r[n].exports;var o=r[n]={exports:{},id:n,loaded:!1};return t[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,e),o.loaded=!0,o.exports}var r={};return e.m=t,e.c=r,e.p="",e(0)}([function(t,e,r){"use strict";function n(t,e){"object"===("undefined"==typeof t?"undefined":i(t))&&(e=t,t=void 0),e=e||{};var r,n=s(t),a=n.source,p=n.id,f=n.path,l=h[p]&&f in h[p].nsps,d=e.forceNew||e["force new connection"]||!1===e.multiplex||l;return d?(u("ignoring socket cache for %s",a),r=c(a,e)):(h[p]||(u("new io instance for %s",a),h[p]=c(a,e)),r=h[p]),n.query&&!e.query?e.query=n.query:e&&"object"===i(e.query)&&(e.query=o(e.query)),r.socket(n.path,e)}function o(t){var e=[];for(var r in t)t.hasOwnProperty(r)&&e.push(encodeURIComponent(r)+"="+encodeURIComponent(t[r]));return e.join("&")}var i="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof 
and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io is based on the webSocket transport.  And, the webSocket transport starts every connection with an http request (with certain headers set that indicate it's a webSocket connection request).  As such when you do `io.listen()`, it creates a webServer.

Then, to support some other socket.io stuff (such as fetching the client socket.io library and establishing new connections), it also creates routes based on the `/socket.io` path prefix such as `/socket.io` and `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

> Where are these 'endpoints' defined from?

They are part of the internal workings of socket.io.

> Are these leftovers from past versions?

No, they are still how socket.io works.

> When I go to `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/` I get a 400 bad request

That route is used for new socket.io connections and it requires various query parameters and custom headers in order to do its job properly and that's why you're getting a bad request.

For example, here's a screenshot of the request to start a new socket.io connection using the `/socket.io` route.  You can see both query parameters and custom headers that are part of setting up both the webSocket transport and the socket.io connection on top of that transport.

[image]

Comment: "such as fetching the client socket.io library and establishing new connections" so when I have my socket.io-client, which am I connecting to? var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000') or var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000/socket.io') I think from what you said, it's the former, but if that's the case, how and when would I ever connect to the latter?

Comment: (also im trying different things out in code so I am experimenting, not just blindly asking) TY

Comment: I think my confusion is, since socket.io is based on web sockets, do we always initially establish connection using http first and then it automatically upgrades us to web socket protocol (which in turn is socket.io)? would we ever bypass (does it make sense) the initial http protocol and go straight to web sockets? and this applies in code as well (always go through http first?), that's why I posted that comment above about socket.io-client.

Comment: @jaxkewl - The default behavior for socket.io is a couple of regular http requests and then update to webSocket as the transport.  This was originally done this way when not every client could do webSocket and when some proxies didn't support it (which is rarely  the case any more).  But, you can configure socket.io to immediately start with webSocket which is what the screenshot I posted represents.  This is the initiation of the webSocket transport (with socket.io messaging on top of it).

Comment: @jaxkewl - All webSocket connections start with an http request and then the two sides agree to switch the protocol of that same TCP socket to the webSocket protocol and this has nothing to do with socket.io - the webSocket transport that socket.io uses also starts that same way (with  an http request)..

Comment: @jaxkewl - When you specify `http://localhost:3000` as your socket.io server, the socket.io client library adds the `/socket.io` to the path automatically before contacting the server.  You don't do that.  It does that for you.  You do not have to be aware of the `/socket.io` path at all when connecting.  The only time you specify it is when specifying the client-side socket.io library URL because that's a plain browser URL, not something the socket.io client participates in (as it isn't yet loaded).